# How to use Github OAuth redirect_url parameter?

Tags: api, redirect, oauth, github

I am trying to use the Github Oauth API for a specific purpose:

[Github OAuth API Specs](http://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#redirect-urls)

Here is what I did:

I created an "Application" in my Github account, and added an application URL say **http://example.com/** and a Callback URL **http://example.com/**/. Github, in return, generated a **client_id** and **client_secret**.

I used the **client_id** to generate an authorization url:

```
https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?client_id=<client_id>&scope=repo&redirect_url=http://example.com/auth/
```

When I paste this URL in the browser. Github asks me sign-in. Once I sign in with my credentials, it asks me to authorize the application, which I do. However, it returns to this url with a temporary code:

```
 http://example.com/?code=<temporary code>
```

, instead of the **redirect_url** that I had provided:

```
   http://example.com/auth/?code=<temporary code>
```

In general, I want the flexibility to construct my own **redirect_url**, where I can add few parameters to the **redirect_url** so that I can distinguish between different users.

I'v tried different combinations without any success. I've even tried to encode the **redirect_url** parameter but it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the parameter is not `redirect_url`, it is `redirect_uri` (URL -> URI).